# Comparing an object's key with another object's value in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to compare an object's key with another object's value. This function should return the object(of the key) if they are the same.

```
const obj1 = {
"list": [
{
  sequence: {
    id: '6543'
  }
},
{
  sequence: {
    id: '5667'
  }
},
{
  sequence: {
    id: '7899'
  }
}
]}

const obj2 = {
      "id": "alias",
      "value": {
        "6543": "Htayu",
        "1456": "dfwd"
      }
    }
```

Now I would like to compare obj1.sequence.id with obj2.value.key. I want to compare each object of obj1 with each key of obj2. If they are same then I need obj2 matched key value pair.

For example:

```
obj1 6543 = obj2 6543
const requiredValue = [{"6543": "Htayu"}]
```

I already did this.

```
const customName = obj2.find((obj) => obj.id === 
 'alias');
const name = Object.keys(customName.value);
```

It is not working. Please help!

Comment: Your definition of `obj1` is problematic: it has an object literal with multiple keys with the same name. Only the object with `id` 12345 will remain accessible. Object keys are unique.

Comment: @trincot thanks for noticing! please check now.

Comment: What exactly is the expected output for this example? And how would it look if there are two or more matches?

Comment: @trincot if the id in obj1 matches a key in obj2 then I need the matched key value pair from obj2. id from obj1 6543 is matched with key 6543 from obj2. So now I need this key value pair from obj2 "6543": "Htayu".

Comment: Can you show in JavaScript syntax the *exact* data structure you want to get as result when there are more matches? Is the second key value pair then part of the same object, or a new object in the same array, ...etc. Just given the JavaScript syntax of the output in a more general case (with more than one match) would be helpful. What if the same id occurs twice? Is that ignored in the output, or will there be a duplicate there too?

Comment: OK, this is not answering my question. I will leave this to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const obj1 = {
    "list": [
        {
            sequence: {
                id: '6543'
            }
        },
        {
            sequence: {
                id: '5667'
            }
        },
        {
            sequence: {
                id: '7899'
            }
        }
    ]
}

const obj2 = {
    "id": "alias",
    "value": {
        "6543": "Htayu",
        "1456": "dfwd"
    }
}

let data = Object.entries(obj2.value).filter(a => obj1.list.filter(x => x.sequence.id === a[0])).map(a => {
    return {[a[0]]: a[1]};
});
console.log(data);
```

Comment: my data was wrong. I have corrected it now. Please check

Comment: @BhagyaSwamy, code is updated.